# Experience map/Customer journey Card game

Tags: customer-experience

some years ago, one of my coworker used a visual card game to help define a, ideal customer Journey around an e-commerce site.

Based on a set of small visual item (like Customer, action like search or pay, etc..), used to build collaborativly a path and optimize it. It helped a lot our team and customer on defining the future product.
Unfortunatly, i'm not in touch anymore with her, and i didn't keep any information on this card game method.

Edit : i'm aware of the plex card. What i've seen is a more "operational" set of cards.

Does anyone have seen similar methods and luckily have ressource to point me at?

Thanks,
Antoine (and sorry for the approximative English)

Answer (score 1):

I found this Customer Journey board game: http://inspiredbycoffee.com/2015/03/consumer-journey-boardgame/

Hope it helps

Comment: I think this is what @Antonie is looking for. But Daniele, could you please populate the answer with required information and images from the link in order to prevent long-time link rotting. Thank you in advance.